CubeIDE don't allow to debug and run code
I'm beginer at stm32 programming. I just install cubeIDE and try to make blink code. But cubeIDE shows this message: "ST-Link Server is required to lounch the debug session"

I have tried to reinstal st-link drivers, but nothing have changed

Maybe you could [edit] your question to tell us a lot more information about your setup? We're not in the room with you. What kind of STM32 do you have? Is it an STM dev board, or a custom PCB? What OS are you running on your computer? How do you connect your computer to the STM32? With an ST-Link?

I recommend you to use STM32CubeMX to build a new project, then right click on project name and configure correct ST-Link setting just like the image below.
Remember first time you want to debug the project, STM32CubeIDE might try to update your ST-Link Driver.

